# What version of scipy and matplotlib should I install on Mac Mountain Lion?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, installation, scipy

I wish to install python numpy, scipy, and matplotlib packages. I used the following:

```
sudo port install py27-numpy py27-scipy py27-matplotlib py27-ipython +notebook py27-pandas py27-sympy py27-nose
```

I was able to install and run numpy, but not scipy or matplotlib. I get an error, "No module named scipy", even though installation appeared to proceed normally. I suspect that this has something to do with the version of scipy and bumpy. I am running OS X Version 10.8.4, python 2.7.2 and numpy 1.6.1. I suspect the problem is either the version or the directory which scipy is installed; scipy is in /Users/myname/src/scipy. I couldn't find out where numpy is located (how can this be done? Spotlight search does not indicate file directory, and grep hangs). How can I install scipy and other packages?

Comment: That's not where Python packages get installed to. Most likely scipy is actually somewhere like `/opt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy`, with `numpy` right alongside.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be 100% sure without a little more information, but I'm 99% sure…

Your problem is that you're installing all this stuff for the MacPorts Python, but then trying to run Apple's Python, which doesn't have any of it installed. (Part of the reason I suspect this is that Apple's Python is version 2.7.2, while MacPorts has been on 2.7.5 for a long time now. The other part of the reason is that this is exactly the same kind of problem people have when they install two different Python X.Y versions without realizing that's what they're doing.)

If you want to use the MacPorts Python, run `/opt/local/bin/python` instead of just `python`.

If you know what you're doing, you can change your `PATH`, or create a symlink, etc., but I suspect you will just confuse yourself further.

---

I personally think you'd be a lot happier just sticking to Apple's Python. You need to install a Fortran compiler with MacPorts (or Homebrew, or manually, or …), but to install Python packages, just use `pip`.

(At this point, that last bit of advice probably won't help you, as the first `pip` on your PATH is probably the MacPorts one, and doesn't match the first `python` on your PATH. But if you're willing to start over, just `port uninstall python`, and then look at [these](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/02/installing-scipy-etc-with-apples-python.html) [blog](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/02/installing-scipy-etc-for-python-3-on-mac.html) [posts](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/02/sticking-with-apples-python-27.html) or the dozens of related questions here on SO.)